# why would "as list" be greyed out in finder?

Tags: macos, finder, ui

I was just now trying to give some support to my 90-year-old father-in-law over the phone, and apparently the "as list" option under Finder / View was greyed out/disabled. The only option he could select was "as column". I can't even imagine why that would be, I'm stumped. Can anyone suggest a hint?

Comment: Maybe it's already in list view?